# How to add startActivity into OnClickListener in Adapter?

Tags: android

Here is my Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
// IF the viaew under inflation and population is header or Item
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java

private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
private String email;       //String Resource for header view email
static Context context;


// Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
// ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    int Holderid;

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView profile;
    TextView Name;
    TextView email;
    Context contxt;
    Intent intent;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
        super(itemView);
        contxt = c;
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(Click);

        // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

        if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
            Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
        }
        else{


            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
            profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
            Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
        }
    }



    private View.OnClickListener Click=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(getPosition())
            {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, Me.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    };
}



MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name,String Email, int Profile,Context passedContext){ // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
    // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
    mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
    mIcons = Icons;
    name = Name;
    email = Email;
    profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed values to the values we declared here
    this.context = passedContext;

    //in adapter



}



//Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
//Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
// if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
// and pass it to the view holder

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

        ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhItem; // Returning the created object

        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

        ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhHeader; //returning the object created


    }
    return null;

}

//Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
// Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
// which view type is being created 1 for item row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
        // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
        holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
    }
    else{

        holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
        holder.Name.setText(name);
        holder.email.setText(email);
    }
}

// This method returns the number of items present in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
}


// Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
```

}

Here is OnClickListener within it

```
    private View.OnClickListener Click=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(getPosition())
            {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, Me.class);
                    startActivity(intent); // ERROR!
            }
        }

    };
}
```

I'm trying put startActivity in it, but it's getting error.
How can I handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below.

```
private View.OnClickListener Click=new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(getPosition())
                {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(context, Me.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent); // or
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace Context with Activity.

```
class Loading extends Thread
{
Activity act;
public Loading(Activity a)
{
    this.act = a;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    act.startActivity(new Intent(act,
            MainActivityLoadingOverlay.class));

    //Thread.currentThread();
    try {
        sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    act.startActivity(new Intent(act,
            MainActivity.class));
}
}
```

It is an example how I tried to make such functionality